# How to keep/access copy of original Feed file when using HTTP Fetcher?

Tags: 7, feeds

I've created Feeds importer to parse remote XML feed using HTTP Fetcher fetcher and I've created content type for that importer and *Attached* to it in *Settings*.

So my feed and import works fine after I've created importer node based on remote Feed URL.

However I would like to keep original remote XML feed file (fetched from the provided URL) similar as this happens for *File upload fetcher* to have a record/copy of it.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: I provide a solution for you, maybe in later I come and filled it with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a simple solution for you but in this time I have not enough time to test it by myself.

First find your importer `form_id`, then in your custom module add custom submit handler then get URL of uploaded file then save it in where you want with [`system_retrieve_file()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_retrieve_file/7), e.g.:

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id == "importer_form_id") {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'yourcustom_form_submit_handler';
  }
}

function yourcustom_form_submit_handler($form, $form_state){
  // dpm($form_state['values']);
  // find file url and put it in $url
  // then try to fetch it with system_retrieve_file
  system_retrieve_file($url);
}
```